# Where can I find my 'user_key' for launchDarkly client?

Tags: react-native, launchdarkly

I'm setting up the client on my React Native project

```
let client = new LDClient();
let config = { "mobileKey": "YOUR_MOBILE_KEY" };
let user = { "key": "user_key" }; // where do I find this info?

await client.configure(config, user);
```

I'm currently getting as a return value to this `{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}` assuming that's because of the missing `user_key`.

Where can I find my `user_key`?

Answer (score 1):

`user_key` is a unique string that identifies the user loading the website. It's something that you need to provide. LaunchDarkly needs to be able to differentiate your users in order to do things like partial rollouts.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you got the `user_key` from launchDarkly or you can check it in their API documentation on how to get the `user_key`

As for the problem where you get `{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}`, this is what you get when you log `Promise` before it resolve.